# TextBox in Silverlight 5 not update

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I migrated the application pro SilverLight 5 as well as the client. After this update the textbox does not update client data, even implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged.

THAT SAME IN SILVERLIGHT 4 APPLICATION WORKS, THE DETAILS ARE TIMELY TEXTBOX NORMALLY AFTER RaisePropertyChanged.

Follow my textbox:

```
<TextBox Width="43" MaxLength="4" slf:TextBoxFilterService.Filter="PositiveInteger"
    IsEnabled="{Binding DadosServicoEnabled}" Margin="6,0" Text="{Binding
    Path=HoraDataEntradaVeiculo, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,Mode=TwoWay, 
    Converter={StaticResource HoraConverter}}"/>
```

Follow properties

```
public string _HoraDataEntradaVeiculo;
public string HoraDataEntradaVeiculo
{
    get
    {
        return _HoraDataEntradaVeiculo;
    }
    set
    {
        _HoraDataEntradaVeiculo = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("HoraDataEntradaVeiculo");    
    }
}
```

Someone can tell me if the version 5 update changed the way??

Answer (score 1):

This used to happen to me after upgrading to Silverlight 5. It would fail to update when run from the IDE and using the browser page started by the IDE. If you run your project from IDE and then start your own browser and browse to the page being tested, the TextBox should update as expected.

It appears to be resolved with my projects now. Maybe there are updates you haven't installed or I'm just lucky at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for responding. And really tested when implemented by IDE has this behavior by running a new browser update is successful.

Thank you

Comment: Great! Please "accept" the answer by clicking on the transparent tick to the left of my answer. The tick should go green.